# Add solution file and jsproj file to cloned repo in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, cordova

I cloned a repository from Team Explorer in Visual Studio which came with a folder with Cordova directories and all the code but there's no solution or jsproj file to build the project with. The repo is for a Apache Cordova application. I can open the folder in Visual Studio and view all the files, but again, I can't build/debug it. What are the steps I need to take after cloning a repository for adding a solution to the project so I can build it? Here is what the folder looks like after cloning:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering there is an .idea folder, check first if yu can [use IntelliJ IDEA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems) in order to open and possibly build the project.

That IDE has a [Cordova plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7436-phonegap-cordova-plugin) (but only in its [Ultimate Edition though](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/phonegap-cordova.html))